# Disable check disk stats every login

Tags: boot, 20.04, login, disk, disk-check

I was able to remove all of my boot error messages in Ubuntu 20.04.1 .
I like to know, if it's possible to disable/skip this message before login. I checked my SSD disk and no errors found. I am using dual-boot.
Thanks for your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Does it affect the boot speed?

Comment: No. It's just unnecessary.

Comment: Why is a system check unnecessary?

Comment: See:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: How edit fstab? There is multiple commands. Is it fsck=0 ?

Comment: It's really a bad idea to disable `fsck` at system boot time. It only takes seconds. You can end up with a corrupted file system. Don't edit /etc/fstab.